# JDBC NullPointerException

Tags: java, jdbc

Установлен Eclipse, создан maven проект, в мавен установлена зависимость

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.41</version>
</dependency>
```

Создан класс SQLClass, в нем реализован метод Conn()

```
public static void Conn() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { //нет класса
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Ошибка

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(DriverManager.java:344)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(DriverManager.java:317)
    at net.javamaster.blog.dao.SQLClass.Conn(SQLClass.java:28)
    at net.javamaster.blog.dao.SQLClass.getAllPosts(SQLClass.java:67)
    at net.javamaster.blog.dao.SQLClass.main(SQLClass.java:344)
```

Я создал точно такой-же класс и метод, но скомпилировал руками, и всё работает нормально, не понимаю почему в эклипсе не работает.

Comment: Я убрал в методе main вызов метода Conn(),но он всё равно продолжает ссылаться на этот вызов из main, я почистил кэш, перезапустил эклипс, это не помогло, не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: Решилось все тем, что я заново пересобрал проект

Comment: Из стека вызовов следует, что `Conn` вызывается не прямо, а через `getAllPosts`.